# QListWidget get current row without hidden Object

Tags: qt, qlistwidget, qlistview

Is it possible to get the current row of a `QListWidget` item without counting hidden items?

For example I have 3 items so it will be row 0 until 2. If I hide now the second item it shows of course only items 1 and 3 but `ui->listWidget->currentRow()` for item 3 returns 2 but as one item is hidden it's visual now in row one and not more two.

How I can get the current row without counting the hidden items?
The problem is that it can be hidden also more then one item and not successive. So counting the hidden items doesn't help.

I hope it's understandable what I mean.

Comment: Try to use `QStandardItemModel` + create your own `QSortFilterProxyModel` to filter out "hidden" entries. In that case you can work with selection model and get actual indexes. But it is unclear for me, in what usecases you'll need such stuff.

Comment: So, you need the user-visible row number of an item? For what purpose? Maybe there's another way to make what you want happen.

Comment: I have a QWebview with multicanvas, the QList shows the Objects from the current activ canvas. As I didn't wanted to make for each Canvas a separate ItemModel I just hide the Items but, to interact with the Objects on Canvas I need the correct Row as it's the Index of the Objects.